# ./gradlew build Unable to Resolve Dependencies

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I'm working on a git project (I cloned it using SourceTree) that uses a gradle wrapper for building, testing

*By the way, I was told I had to change the names of a bunch of the projects, dependencies etc. to be allowed to ask the question, so sorry for the weird, generic names*

The only problem is, I'm unable to build it. Whenever I run `./gradlew build`, I get this error:

```
Normal Build:

    :project-name:compileJava

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':project-name:compileClasspath'.
    > Could not resolve bar-group:common:0.1-SNAPSHOT.
      Required by:
          foo-project:project-name:0.1
       > Could not resolve bar-group:common:0.1-SNAPSHOT.
          > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://valid.artifactory.url//artifactory/libs-release/bar-group/common/0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.
             > Could not GET 'http://valid.artifactory.url//artifactory/libs-release/bar-group/common/0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'.
                > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
    > Could not resolve bar-group:clients:0.1-SNAPSHOT.
      Required by:
          foo-project:project-name:0.1
       > Could not resolve bar-group:clients:0.1-SNAPSHOT.
          > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://valid.artifactory.url//artifactory/libs-release/bar-group/clients/0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.
             > Could not GET 'http://valid.artifactory.url//artifactory/libs-release/bar-group/clients/0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'.
                > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

    BUILD FAILED

    Total time: 7.418 secs
```

Nobody else in the project is getting this error (there's about 50 people using it).

From what I can tell, gradle is trying to find maven-metadata.xml and then throwing a fit when it can't find it (because it doesn't exist). I've had a talk with one of the admins of the project and he said that it shouldn't need to look for it (he also said that clones on other people's machines were looking for it, not finding it, then just grabbing the dependencies some other way).

When you go to `http://valid.artifactory.url//artifactory/libs-release/bar-group/common/0.1-SNAPSHOT/` you can see a common-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar and .pom, with sha1 and md5 hashes of each (the url is obviously different, just take my word for it :D).

There's a bunch I've done to try and fix it. I've made a whole bunch of fresh clones, I've uninstalled and reinstalled jdk, I've installed Maven (then uninstalled).

I'm on a Macbook Air 11", running El Capitan 10.11.6

My Java version is:

```
java version "1.8.0_102"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_102-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.102-b14, mixed mode)
```

By the way, I'm fairly new to java/gradle so I apologise if there's some really stupid thing I've done wrong that's causing this. Also, I have extremely limited access to any admin stuff with the project.

For extra detail, there's the [build.gradle file](http://pastebin.com/SkiVk9NW) I'm using, the output of [./gradlew build --debug](http://pastebin.com/Sc1ZKSpT) and the output of [./gradlew build --stacktrace](http://pastebin.com/6qzEDPmT).

Comment: What is the output if you run `./gradlew` version?

Comment: @mkobit `./gradlew -version` gives [this output](http://pastebin.com/Nun4Shf5)

Comment: Hmm I thought it might be because Gradle is running with a different Java version. Nothing else comes off the top of my head.